# Locale in mongoregex

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

Hi I have a problem in mongoregex when Insensitive Case search. In Turkish language the uppercase of i is İ not I, and we have a ı char and uppercase of that is I.

```
ı->I
i->İ
```

I have a record in database like "Anıl" and when I search with;

```
    $rxp = new MongoRegex('/Il/i');
```

it must match the record. But it doesn't.

I tried locale flag;

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "turkish","tr_TR.UTF-8");
    $rxp = new MongoRegex('/Il/il');
```

doesn't work either...

Comment: try it within `[]`..so it would be `[Il]`

Comment: If I do that regexp will try to match `I` or `l`, I need exact match of `Il` but case insensitive in the record.

Comment: you can use unicode character representation